# How to horizontal-scale a service using MongoDB implementing SELECT... FOR UPDATE and Transactions?

Tags: database, mongodb, concurrency, locking, horizontal-scaling

I'm trying to achieve in the best way possible a pessimistic lock using MongoDB.

**Goal**

I would like to H scale a service which:

1. takes from a MongoDB collection a list of data based on a limit parameter and a query filter
2. process each data doing some changes to each of the obtained documents and some other stuff
3. update each document on the database

So ideally I could run N instances which process 1,2,3 as soon as I'm able to avoid getting the same documents to be processed at step 1.

**Test**

I've checked the documentation and played around with some basic code snippets and I've ended up that:

- even using transactions, doing a separately find and update, it wont
  prevent to any other transaction to process the same data. It will be
  prevented only if the update method has been already invoked even if the
  transaction is not committed yet
- if two transactions performs an update on the same document and the
  second transaction commits before the first one, the changes of the first one
  are going to be discarder. So the last transaction started on the same document wins

**Conclusion**

MongoDB Transactions are not useful in my use-case.

Instead of using a LIMIT for my find result, LIMIT will be the number of times I will be performing a findAndUpdate in order to avoid to find and process the same data from the scaled services

```
const promises = []

for (let i = 0; i <= LIMIT - 1; i += 1) {
  promises.push(
    db.collection(COLLECTION)
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { status: 'active', lock: 'NONE' },
        { $set: { lock: 'ACTIVE' } },
        { returnOriginal: false }))
}

const itemsToBeProcessed = await Promise.all(promises)

... stuff like updating each object

... update each document with proper object (setting lock to NONE again)
```

Am I doing it correctly? Any advise or resources?

Answer (score 0):

Generally locking reduces scalability compared to lock-free solutions, since while a lock is held other operations are blocked.

If you intend to use locking to **reserve a work item**, you shouldn't be holding locks (= having open transactions) while the item is being actually processed (after it's assigned to a worker for processing). You could implement reservation itself using transactions, or potentially a much simpler solution like a conditional update. On the flip side you would generally need some kind of a mechanism to detect dead workers and release reservations whose work stopped due to failure.

If you are using transactions over essentially your complete data set (rather than reservation system only) this doesn't scale and you'll likely need to rearchitect your processing code.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is to be able to run multiple containers which process MongoDB documents. While each set of document is being processed it should not be available to the others containers which instead will try to process the same data